# Java String Replace on an XML pattern

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, replaceall

I have the following XML String:

```
String XML = "<TEST><MESSAGEID>5435646578</MESSAGEID></TEST>";
```

The number in the xml string keeps changing so I want to do a string replace and want to make the XML into

```
<TEST><MESSAGEID></MESSAGEID></TEST>
```

I am looking for doing something like this but I'm not sure how to get the pattern for the first argument in the replaceAll method.

```java
public class HelloWorld {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String XML = "<MESSAGEID>5435646578</MESSAGEID>";
        String newStr = XML.replaceAll("<MESSAGEID>*</MESSAGEID>", "<MESSAGEID></MESSAGEID>");
        System.out.println(newStr);
    }
}
```

Comment: try replacing your `*` in `uotmXML.replaceAll("<MESSAGEID>*</MESSAGEID>"` with `[^<]+`. This will match everything until the `<` character

Comment: This worked for me. If you would like to add it as an answer as opposed to a comment, I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try replacing your `*` in `uotmXML.replaceAll("<MESSAGEID>*</MESSAGEID>", ...` with `[^<]+`. This will match everything until the `<` character

Answer (score 3):

The pattern `<MESSAGEID>[0-9]+</MESSAGEID>` would work. If the structure of your input can change, you may want to use an XML parser instead.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the alphanumeric pattern unless you're absolutely certain it'll just be numeric:

```java
// alphanumeric
String newStr = uotmXML.replaceAll("<MESSAGEID>\w+</MESSAGEID>", "<MESSAGEID></MESSAGEID>");

// digits
String newStr = uotmXML.replaceAll("<MESSAGEID>\d+</MESSAGEID>", "<MESSAGEID></MESSAGEID>");
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the regex `^<MESSAGEID>(\d+)</MESSAGEID>$` to find the digits (in group 1), if you are guaranteed the format won't change. Otherwise I would use a proper XML library like JAXB or Jackson.